# How to make a menu that repeats in C

Tags: c, menu

I'm making a file compressor program in C, and I'm creating a friendly menu that appears in the beginning of the program.

That's the simplified code:

**Compress.c**

```
int main()
{

    char directory[100];
    char option;
    bool exit = false;

    do
    {

        printf("|------------------------------------|\n");
        printf("|             Welcome!               |\n");
        printf("|                                    |\n");
        printf("|Select one of the following options:|\n");
        printf("|    1 - Compress a file             |\n");
        printf("|    2 - Decompress a file           |\n");
        printf("|    3 - Exit                        |\n");
        printf("|------------------------------------|\n");

        scanf(" %c", &option);

        switch(option)
        {
            case '1':
                printf("Enter the FULL directory or drag HERE the file you want to COMPRESS: \n");
                scanf(" %s", directory);

                /* COMPRESS FILE */

                break;

            case '2':
                printf("Enter the FULL directory or drag HERE the file you want to UNCOMPRESS: \n");
                scanf(" %s", directory);

                /* DECOMPRESS FILE */

                break;

            case '3':
                exit = true;
                break;

            default:
                printf("Invalid option!\n\n");
                break;
        }
    }while(exit == false);

    return 0;
}
```

After typing '1', for example, and typing a CORRECT directory, the program prints 10 times the menu and returns 0. But when I type an INVALID or NONEXISTENT directory, it works, because it prints only 1 time the menu and waits for user types the option again!

Why is it doing that?

Comment: The simplified code you posted works fine. The problem must be in original non simplified code you didn't post.

Comment: @DavidRanieri it's `do{ switch{...} }while(...)`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I tested my program now, and I discovered that it only doesn't works when I type a file that has spaces in its name (like `Hello World.mp3`). `Hello-World.mp3` works fine.

Comment: @Jabberwocky but the fact is: before I created that menu, it was working fine with all type of files, including the one that has spaces in its name.

Comment: You're asking about the usage of `scanf`. `scanf` is not good for interactive user input. Use `fgets` and scan the string yourself (possibly using `sscanf` depending on what you want to do).

Comment: @grandtour: That's the behaviour of scanf() for the specifier that you gave it.

Comment: @Grandtour you should put a \ before the space when inputting your file name: `Hello\ World.mp3`

Comment: @Silveris that's not really a good advice. And it's actually plain wrong anyway. It's not a shell issue but a scanf issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `scanf(" %s")` to this, did the trick:

```
getchar();
gets(directory);

//AFTER READING THAT DIRECTORY, WE NEED TO CHECK IF IT HAS QUOTES ON IT:
if(directory[0] == '\"')  //IF IT HAS, ENTER HERE
{
    /* REMOVE ALL QUOTES IN THE DIRECTORY */
}
```